# Generate Laravel URL using URI segments instead of query string

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the following code to generate a link:

```
{{ URL::route('monthly',array($year,$month_number)) }}
```

Which looks like

/monthly?1999&5

But what I really need is:

/monthly/1999/5

How should I accomplish this?

Comment: what does your route look like? it should look like `Route::get('monthly/{year}/{month} ...`

Comment: This should be handled automatically for you if you have a route that exists that matches `Route::get('monthly/{year}/{month_number}')` as the 2nd argument `params` should be applied into the constructor. Something else is going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a route to support those parameters:

```
Route::get('montly/{year}/{month_number}', 'ControllerName@show');
```

And your controller method:

```
public function show($year, $month_number)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wow that did it! I wasn't thinking this would be an automatic thing.... bad assumption in Laravel. This is so convenient. Thanks!